# Motivation of a proof related to cofactor matrices and determinants

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

I came across this theorem in Apostol's Calculus II under the chapter 'Determinants'.I understood the proof,however I fail to recognize the motivation behind the new matrix $B$ whose $i$th row is equal to the $k$th row of A for some $i \neq k$.This step in the proof doesn't seem very obvious to me.

---

**Theorem**:
For any $n \times n$ matrix $A$ with $n \geq 2$ we have,

(3.29) $A(cof A)^t=(det A)I$

In particular,if $det A\neq 0$,the inverse of $A$ exists and is given by

$A^{-1}=\frac{1}{det A}(cof A)^t$

Here is the proof from the textbook:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/wXL6U.png

Answer (score 0):

The proof considers matrix B which is identical to A except $i^{th}$ row of A is same as $k^{th}$ row. With this consideration of B, $$det{B}=0$$ since the two rows are same. further it can be written as $$\sum_{j=1}^{j=n}{B_{ij}}(cof{B})_{ij}=0$$

Now, why does the author introduce the B matrix? I think it is just to explain that if we consider $$\sum_{j=1}^{j=n}{A_{ij}}(cof{A})_{kj} $$the sum of elements of a row with the product of cofactor of another row then the product goes to zero (which is similar to taking the determinant of a matrix whose two rows are same, matrix B).